# Problems with moving site to VPS

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

I moved my site to a VPS server and now I'm getting this error:

```
Error displaying the error page: JERROR_COULD_NOT_FIND_TEMPLATE
```

What is it about? Is it a problem with my hosting or just something wrong in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I would try:
Disabling all plugins and moudules which were not there when you installed joomla for the first time.
I would also look at your configuration.php to make sure everything is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

First check permissions for the files and then check that your configuration.php file is present and readable and that the MySQL connection settings are still correct.